# Error occurs in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could you please suggest where syntax mistake occurs?

When I run this code in Oracle, I have no mistake, but in Microsoft SQL Server I catch an error connected with syntax "near where"

Thanks in advance for your help

```
select 
    a.orderlinenumber, b.categorytype 
from
    (select *  
     from  
         (select *  
          from Anton
          where OrderLineNumber in (select OrderLineNumber 
                                    from Anton 
                                    group by OrderLineNumber 
                                    having COUNT (CategoryType) = 2) )
    where CategoryType = 'Money back') a
right join
    (select * 
     from  
         (select * 
          from Anton
          where OrderLineNumber in (select OrderLineNumber  
                                    from Anton 
                                    group by OrderLineNumber 
                                    having COUNT (CategoryType) = 2))
     where 
         CategoryType <> 'Money back') b on a.OrderLineNumber = b.OrderLineNumber;
```

Comment: You need something after the `select` and before the `from`.  You might consider asking another question with sample data and desired results and an explanation of what you want to do.  There is probably a simpler method.

Comment: Your SUBQUERY SELECT is missing the column names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the columns you are selecting, and you should also alias both sub queries:

```
select  a.orderlinenumber,
        b.categorytype 
from
(
        select  [COLUMNS HERE]
        from  (
        SELECT  [COLUMNS HERE]
        FROM Anton
        WHERE OrderLineNumber IN (SELECT OrderLineNumber FROM Anton GROUP BY OrderLineNumber HAVING COUNT (CategoryType)=2) 
        ) AS ab
        where CategoryType = 'Money back'
) AS a
right join 
(
        select  [COLUMNS HERE]
        from  (
        SELECT  [COLUMNS HERE]
        FROM Anton
        WHERE OrderLineNumber IN (SELECT OrderLineNumber FROM Anton GROUP BY OrderLineNumber HAVING COUNT (CategoryType)=2) 
        ) AS ac
        where CategoryType <> 'Money back'
) AS b on a.OrderLineNumber=b.OrderLineNumber;
```

Replace [COLUMNS HERE] with the columns you wish to select.

Answer (score 0):

If you want rows in `anton` that have two rows, one of which is `'Moneyback'` then you could do something like this:

```
SELECT OrderLineNumber, MIN(CategoryType), MAX(CategoryType)
FROM Anton 
GROUP BY OrderLineNumber
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN CategoryType = 'Moneyback' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1;
```

This will return the two categories on a single row.

Answer (score 0):

This worked when I tried the code, it needed a name for the first FROM.

```
select a.orderlinenumber,b.categorytype from
(
select*  from  (SELECT*  FROM Anton
WHERE OrderLineNumber IN (SELECT OrderLineNumber FROM Anton 
GROUP BY OrderLineNumber HAVING COUNT (CategoryType)=2) ) AS a
where CategoryType = 'Money back')a

right join

(
select * from  (SELECT * FROM Anton
WHERE OrderLineNumber IN (SELECT OrderLineNumber FROM Anton 
GROUP BY OrderLineNumber HAVING COUNT (CategoryType)=2) ) AS b
where CategoryType <> 'Money back')b

on a.OrderLineNumber=b.OrderLineNumber;
```